# How to count the number of a specific character in each line?

Tags: text-processing

I was wondering how to count the number of a specific character in each line by some text processing utilities?

For example, to count `"` in each line of the following text

```
"hello!" 
Thank you!
```

The first line has two, and the second line has 0.

Another example is to count `(` in each line.

Comment: Just going to add that you received much increased performance by writing your own 10 line C program for this rather than using regular expressions with sed. You should consider doing depending on the size of your input files.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can do it with `sed` and `awk`:

```
$ sed 's/[^"]//g' dat | awk '{ print length }'
2
0
```

Where `dat` is your example text, sed deletes (for each line) all non-`"` characters and `awk` prints for each line its size (i.e. `length` is equivalent to `length($0)`, where `$0` denotes the current line).

For another character you just have to change the sed expression. For example for `(` to:

```
's/[^(]//g'
```

**Update:** `sed` is kind of overkill for the task - `tr` is sufficient. An equivalent solution with `tr` is:

```
$ tr -d -c '"\n' < dat | awk '{ print length; }'
```

Meaning that `tr` deletes all characters which are not (`-c` means complement) in the character set `"\n`.

Comment: +1 should be more efficient than the `tr`&`wc` version.

Comment: Yes, but can it handle Unicode?

Comment: @amphetamachine, yes - at least a quick test with `ß` (utf hex: c3 9f) (instead of `"`) works as expected, i.e. `tr`, `sed` and `awk` do complement/replacement/counting without a problem - on a Ubuntu 10.04 system.

Comment: Most versions of `tr`, including GNU tr and classic Unix tr, operate on single byte characters and are not Unicode compliant.. Quoted from [Wikipedia tr (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) .. Try this snippet: `echo "aā⧾c" | tr "ā⧾" b` ... on Ubuntu 10.04 ... `ß` is a single byte *Extended Latin* char and is handled by `tr`...  The real issue here is not that `tr` doesn't handle Unicode (because ALL characters are Unicode), it  is really that `tr` only handles one-byte at a time..

Comment: @fred, no, ß is not a single byte character - its  Unicode position is U+00DF, which is coded as 'c3 9f' in UTF-8, i.e. **two** bytes.

Comment: What if I need to count the number of occurrences of two specific consecutive characters (e.g. `,,`)? I imagine it should be easy but the `sed` pattern `s/[^,,]//g` didn't work.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina It *cannot* work, by design. Translated into human-readable prose, `s/[^,,]//g` means: find everything that is __not a comma__ and remove it. Note that this is a `[^character]`construction, which __excludes__ the character following the caret `^`. This should explain why your multiple commas are ignored and interpreted as one single one.

Comment: Consider `wc -c ` as a potentially less-overkill alternative to `awk` here.

Comment: @AhmedFasih, `wc -c` counts all characters over all lines - including newlines - not the number of characters for **each line**. Thus, you can't use it as direct replacement for the `awk` part in my answer.

Answer (score 76):

I would just use awk

```
awk -F\" '{print NF-1}' <fileName>
```

Here we set the field separator (with the -F flag) to be the character `"` then all we do is print number of fields `NF` - 1. The number of occurrences of the target character will be one less than the number of separated fields.

For funny characters that are interpreted by the shell you just need to make sure you escape them otherwise the command line will try and interpret them. So for both `"` and `)` you need to escape the field separator (with `\`).

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to use singles quotes instead for escaping. It will work with any character (except `'`). Also, it has a strange behavior with empty lines.

Comment: The question specifically uses `"` so I feel obliged to make the code work with it. It depends what shell you are using weather the character needs to be escaped but bash/tcsh will both need to escape "

Comment: Of course, but there is no problem with `-F'"'`.

Comment: +1 What a good idea to use FS.... This will resolve the blank-line showing -1, and, for example, the "$1" from the bash commandline. ... `awk -F"$1" '{print NF==0?NF:NF-1}' filename`

Comment: Also work with multiple chars as separator... useful !

Answer (score 19):

Using `tr` ard `wc`:

```bash
function countchar()
{
    while IFS= read -r i; do printf "%s" "$i" | tr -dc "$1" | wc -m; done
}
```

Usage:

```bash
$ countchar '"' <file.txt  #returns one count per line of file.txt
1
3
0

$ countchar ')'           #will count parenthesis from stdin
$ countchar '0123456789'  #will count numbers from stdin
```

Comment: Note. `tr` doesn't handle characters which use more than one byte.. [see Wikipedia tr (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) .. ie. `tr` is not Unicode compliant.

Comment: [You're running 4 commands for every line of the file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/22565)

Comment: you need to remove whitespace characters from `$IFS`, otherwise `read` will trim them from the start and end.

Comment: you [can't use `echo` for arbitrary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22565)

Comment: @Peter.O, some `tr` implementations support multibyte characters, but `wc -c` counts bytes, not characters anyway (need `wc -m` for characters).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: My answer was not trying to deal with the corner cases, but thanks, now it should work most of the time.

Comment: Well that's disappointing, I was looking forward to a Battle of the Stéphanes.

Answer (score 15):

Yet another implementation that does not rely on external programs, in `bash`, `zsh`, `yash` and some implementations/versions of `ksh`:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  line="${line//[!\"]/}"
  echo "${#line}"
done <input-file
```

Use `line="${line//[!(]}"`for counting `(`.

Comment: When the last line doesn't have a trailing \n, the while loop exits, because although it read the last line, it also returns a non-zero exit code to indicate EOF... to get around it, the following snippet works (..It has been been bugging me for a while, and I've just discovered this workaroung)...  `eof=false; IFS=; until $eof; do read -r || eof=true; echo "$REPLY"; done`

Comment: @Gilles: you added a trailing `/` that is not needed in bash. It is a ksh requirement?

Comment: The trailing `/` is needed in older versions of ksh, and IIRC in older versions of bash as well.

Answer (score 13):

The answers using `awk` fail if the number of matches is too large (which happens to be my situation). For the answer from [loki-astari](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1165/loki-astari), the following error is reported:

```
awk -F" '{print NF-1}' foo.txt 
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="foo.txt" FNR=1 NR=1
```

For the answer from [enzotib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6539/enzotib) (and the equivalent from [manatwork](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10412/manatwork)), a segmentation fault occurs:

```
awk '{ gsub("[^\"]", ""); print length }' foo.txt
Segmentation fault
```

The `sed` solution by [maxschlepzig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1131/maxschlepzig) works correctly, but is slow (timings below).

Some solutions not yet suggested here. First, using `grep`:

```
grep -o \" foo.txt | wc -w
```

And using `perl`:

```
perl -ne '$x+=s/\"//g; END {print "$x\n"}' foo.txt
```

Here are some timings for a few of the solutions (ordered slowest to fastest); I limited things to one-liners here. 'foo.txt' is a file with one line and one long string which contains 84922 matches.

```
## sed solution by [maxschlepzig]
$ time sed 's/[^"]//g' foo.txt | awk '{ print length }'
84922
real    0m1.207s
user    0m1.192s
sys     0m0.008s

## using grep
$ time grep -o \" foo.txt | wc -w
84922
real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.012s

## using perl
$ time perl -ne '$x+=s/\"//g; END {print "$x\n"}' foo.txt
84922
real    0m0.034s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.004s

## the winner: updated tr solution by [maxschlepzig]
$ time tr -d -c '\"\n' < foo.txt |  awk '{ print length }'
84922
real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: + good idea! I expanded your table, in a new answer, feel free to edit (the final picture is not so clear, but I believe @maxschlepzig is steel the faster solution)

Comment: maxschlepzig's solution is super fast!

Comment: For your Perl answer, if you're `print`ing the final `$x` in an `END` block, then won't you only get a single-number return? But the OP asked for a count ___per line___ ... ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 I explained in the text that my test example _only had_ a single line, which was my use case. I came to this page (almost 10 years ago :) ) originally trying to find a way that wouldn't break with the number of matches I was dealing with. So you are correct, it does _not_ fit the original question if a file contains more than one line.

Answer (score 13):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk '{print gsub(/"/, "")}' < input-file
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possible implementation with awk and gsub:

```
awk '{ gsub("[^\"]", ""); print length }' input-file
```

The function `gsub` is the equivalent of sed's `'s///g'` .

Use `gsub("[^(]", "")`for counting `(`.

Comment: You can save one character, i.e. when removing the stdin redirection ... ;)

Comment: @maxschlepzig: yeah, of course ;)

Comment: `awk '{print gsub(/"/,"")}' input-file` would be enough, as "For each substring matching the regular expression r in the string t, substitute the string s, and return the number of substitutions." (man awk)

Comment: @maxschlepzig, stdin redirection doesn't have to add one character (`awk '...'<file` is as long as `awk '...' file`), and has several advantages over passing the filename as argument especially with `awk` which chokes on some file names when they contain `=` characters (or start with `-` with older versions of busybox awk)

Answer (score 8):

For a string, the simplest would be with `tr` and `wc` (no need to overkill with `awk` or `sed`) - but note the above comments about `tr`, counts bytes, not characters -

```
echo $x | tr -d -c '"' | wc -m
```

where `$x` is the variable that contains the string (not a file) to evaluate.

Answer (score 6):

I decided to write a C program cause I was bored.

You should probably add input validation, but other than that's all set.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char c = argv[1][0];
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        while (getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1)
        {
                int count = 0;
                char * s = line;
                while (*s) if(*s++ == c) count++;
                printf("%d\n",count);
        }
        if(line) free(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for being bored so that I can learn something. Oh wait, do you need a return?

Comment: **\*shrugs\***, if you want to be fully correct, you also need to add a few more #includes, but the default warnings on my compiler doesn't seem to care.

Comment: You can leave out the `free(line)` because exiting the program implicitly frees all allocated memory - then there is place for a `return 0;` ... ;). Even in examples it is not good style to leave the return code undefined. Btw, `getline` is a GNU extension - in case someone is wondering.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: Is the memory pointed by line allocated by getline()? Is it allocated dynamically on heap by malloc or statically on stack? You said freeing it is not necessary, so is it not allocated dynamically?

Comment: @Tim, yes, the memory pointed to by `line` is allocated by `getline` (after the first successful call of `getline`). `getline` also does `realloc`action if necessary. That means it is allocated dynamically on the heap. And under Unix the heap of a process is destroyed on exit. Btw, the stack is also very dynamic - allocations on the stack may depend on how often a function is called or you can also create dynamically sized arrays on the stack.

Comment: @max: so if not considering that Unix destroys the heap of a process on exit, technically should free() be called explicitly?

Comment: @Tim, yes, e.g. if you refactor the code such that it is a standalone function - say -`f`, which is called several times from other code, then you have to call `free` after the last call of `getline` at the end of this function `f`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another C solution that only needs STD C and less memory:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2 || !*argv[1]) {
    puts("Argument missing.");
    return 1;
  }
  char c = *argv[1], x = 0;
  size_t count = 0;
  while ((x = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
    if (x == '\n') {
      printf("%zd\n", count);
      count = 0;
    } else if (x == c)
      ++count;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not report on the last line if it doesn't have a trailing '\n'

Comment: @fred, yes, which is on purpose, because a line without a trailing `\n` is no real line. This is the same behavior as with my other sed/awk (tr/awk) answer.

Comment: Does this C program handle multibyte characters? Does `á`(U+E1 "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE") and `a` + `   ́  `(U+61 "LATIN SMALL LETTER A" + U+301 "COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT") get counted in an equivalent manner?

Comment: @jubilatious1 no, it just works for ASCII subset.

Answer (score 3):

For a pure bash solution (however, it's bash-specific): If `$x` is the variable containing your string:

```
x2="${x//[^\"]/}"
echo ${#x2}
```

The `${x//` thing removes all chars except `"`, `${#x2}` calculates the length of this rest.

(Original suggestion using `expr` which has problems, see comments: )

```
expr length "${x//[^\"]/}"
```

Comment: Note that it's specific to GNU `expr` and counts bytes, not characters. With other `expr`: `expr "x${x...}" : "x.*" - 1`

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I've modified it using another idea I just had, which has the advantage of not using an external program at all.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `grep` with `regex` to make it more simple and powerful.

To count specific character.

```
$ grep -o '"' file.txt|wc -l
```

To count special characters including whitespace characters.

```
$ grep -Po '[\W_]' file.txt|wc -l
```

Here we are selecting any character with `[\S\s]` and with `-o` option we make `grep` to print each match (which is, each character) in separate line. And then use `wc -l` to count each line.

Comment: OP don't want to print number of all characters in a file! He wants to count/print number of a specific character. for example how many `"` are in each line; and for any other chars. see his question and also accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a more straight forward, purely awk answer would be to use split.
Split takes a string and turns it into an array, the return value is the number of array items generated + 1.

The following code will print out the number of times " appears on each line.

```
awk ' {print (split($0,a,"\"")-1) }' file_to_parse
```

more info on split http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple Python script to find the count of `"` in each line of a file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.count('"')
```

Here we have used the `count` method of built-in `str` type.

Answer (score 3):

**Time comparison of the presented solutions** (not an answer)

The efficiency of the answers is not important. 
Nevertheless, following @josephwb approach, I tried to time all the answers presented.

I use as
input the Portuguese translation of Victor Hugo "Les Miserables" (great book!) and count the occurrences of "a". My edition has 5 volumes, many pages...

```
$ wc miseraveis.txt 
29331  304166 1852674 miseraveis.txt
```

C answers were compiled with gcc, (no optimizations).

Each answer was run 3 times and choose the best.

Don't trust too much these numbers (my 
machine is doing other tasks, etc, etc.). I share these times with you, because I got
some unexpected results and I'm sure you will find some more...

- 14 of 16 timed solutions took less then 1s; 9 less then 0.1s, many of them using pipes
- 2 solutions, using bash line by line, processed the 30k lines by creating new processes, 
  calculate the correct solution in 10s /20s.
- `grep -oP a` is tree times faster then `grep -o a`  (10;11 vs 12)
- The difference between C and others is not so big as I expected. (7;8 vs 2;3)
- (conclusions welcome)

(results in a random order)

```
=========================1 maxschlepzig
$ time sed 's/[^a]//g' mis.txt | awk '{print length}' > a2
real    0m0.704s ; user 0m0.716s
=========================2 maxschlepzig
$ time tr -d -c 'a\n' < mis.txt | awk '{ print length; }' > a12
real    0m0.022s ; user 0m0.028s
=========================3 jjoao
$ time perl -nE 'say y!a!!' mis.txt  > a1
real    0m0.032s ; user 0m0.028s
=========================4 Stéphane Gimenez
$ function countchar(){while read -r i; do echo "$i"|tr -dc "$1"|wc -c; done }

$ time countchar "a"  < mis.txt > a3
real    0m27.990s ; user    0m3.132s
=========================5 Loki Astari
$ time awk -Fa '{print NF-1}' mis.txt > a4
real    0m0.064s ; user 0m0.060s
Error : several -1
=========================6 enzotib
$ time awk '{ gsub("[^a]", ""); print length }' mis.txt > a5
real    0m0.781s ; user 0m0.780s
=========================7 user606723
#include <stdio.h> #include <string.h> // int main(int argc, char *argv[]) ...  if(line) free(line); }

$ time a.out a < mis.txt > a6
real    0m0.024s ; user 0m0.020s
=========================8 maxschlepzig
#include <stdio.h> // int main(int argc, char **argv){if (argc < 2 || !*argv[1]) { ...  return 0; }

$ time a.out a < mis.txt > a7
real    0m0.028s ; user 0m0.024s
=========================9 Stéphane Chazelas
$ time awk '{print gsub(/a/, "")}'< mis.txt > a8
real    0m0.053s ; user 0m0.048s
=========================10 josephwb count total
$ time grep -o a < mis.txt | wc -w > a9
real    0m0.131s ; user 0m0.148s
=========================11 Kannan Mohan count total
$ time grep -o 'a' mis.txt | wc -l > a15
real    0m0.128s ; user 0m0.124s
=========================12 Kannan Mohan count total
$ time grep -oP 'a' mis.txt | wc -l > a16
real    0m0.047s ; user 0m0.044s
=========================13 josephwb Count total
$ time perl -ne '$x+=s/a//g; END {print "$x\n"}'< mis.txt > a10
real    0m0.051s ; user 0m0.048s
=========================14 heemayl
#!/usr/bin/env python2 // with open('mis.txt') as f: for line in f: print line.count('"')

$ time pyt > a11
real    0m0.052s ; user 0m0.052s
=========================15 enzotib
$ time  while IFS= read -r line; do   line="${line//[!a]/}"; echo "${#line}"; done < mis.txt  > a13
real    0m9.254s ; user 0m8.724s
=========================16 bleurp
$ time awk ' {print (split($0,a,"a")-1) }' mis.txt > a14
real    0m0.148s ; user 0m0.144s
Error several -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `a` by the char to be counted. Output is the counter for each line.

```
perl -nE 'say y!a!!'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -n -o \" file | sort -n | uniq -c | cut -d : -f 1
```

where grep does all the heavy lifting: reports each character found at each line number. The rest is just to sum the count per line, and format the output.

Remove the `-n` and get the count for the whole file.

Counting a 1.5Meg text file in under 0.015 secs seems fast.
And does work with characters (not bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'put m:g/\"/.elems;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.match( /\"/, :global).elems.put;'
```

Sample Input (task is to count `"` doublequotes):

```
zero
"two"
"two","four"
"two","four","six"
"two","four","six","eight"
```

Sample Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

---

FYI, I try very hard to stump Raku with Unicode characters and the language performs very well (it does NFC Normalization under-the-hood). It seems to have earned the moniker *"Unicode-ready"*. Below, counting Bengali letters with Raku:

Sample Input (Bengali days-of-the-week from Wikipedia):

```
~$ cat  Bengali_DOW.txt
রবিবার/সূর্যবার Rabibār/Sūryabār
সোমবার/চন্দ্রবার Somabār/Chandrabār
মঙ্গলবার Mangalbār
বুধবার Budhabār
বৃহস্পতিবার/গুরুবার Brihaspatibār/Gurubār
শুক্রবার Shukrabār
শনিবার Shanibār
```

Sample Output (testing with first letter of each line):

```
~$ raku -ne 'put m:g/ <[র সো ম বু বৃ শু শ %]> /.elems;'  Bengali_DOW.txt
3
5
2
2
3
3
2
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#Normalization
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is complicating things so much. I'll give the cleanest, simplest and probably the most performant answer for you:

```bsh
grep -onF '"' input.txt | uniq -c
```

Add `cut -d: -f1` if you would like better format.

Comment: `grep -o | uniq` (including the final `cut`) was already given 7 years before by user79743

Comment: Will your answer count non-ASCII characters? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263691/grep-is-not-matching-non-ascii-characters

Comment: As xhienne writes, duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245314/1131

Comment: Also, it's not the ' most performant answer' - I did a quick test on 2.7 GiB of randomly generated ASCII input and on my Linux laptop in runs in 12 s  wall clock time, whereas the tr+awk method finishes in 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Although most of the answers are really fascinating, I just want to mention another one with the aid of `awk`:

```
$ printf "\"hello!\"                                                                                  
  Thank you!" > data

$ awk '{counter=0; for(i=1;i<=length;i++) if(substr($0,i,1)=="\"") counter++; print counter}' data
2
0
```

In the first part, it counts the number of `"` and then at the END it prints the counter.

Comment: The issue in the answer is fixed now. Please see the update.