# How to sort file by character occurrences per line?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I'm quite new to Linux, and I've found quite a bit of useful information on how to do character counts in a file, but is there a way in Linux/terminal to sort a text file by the number of times a specific character occurs per line?

E.g. given:

```
baseball
aardvark
a man a plan a canal panama
cat
bat
bill
```

Sort by the number of occurrences of the letter "a" yielding:

```
a man a plan a canal panama
aardvark
baseball
cat
bat
bill
```

Regarding "cat" and "bat" at one occurrence of "a" each, I don't care if the order of lines with equal counts get reversed, just interested in a general sort of lines by character frequency.

Comment: If you know [How to count the number of a specific character in each line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18736) you could paste the result and the file, sort by 1st column then delete it, eg. `tr -d -c 'a\n' <infile | awk '{print length}' | paste - infile | sort -k1nr | cut -f2-`

Answer (score 6):

The general approach with this kind of task is to use `awk` or `perl`... to compute the metric you're interested in and prepend it to the line, and then feed that to `sort` and remove the metric off the sorted output:

```
awk '{print gsub("a","a"), $0}' < file | sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: This technique is known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 6):

Another Schwartzian transform:

```
$ awk -Fa '{print NF,$0}' file | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2-
a man a plan a canal panama
aardvark
baseball
cat
bat
bill
```

Or, in Perl:

```
perl -Fa -lane 'print "$#F $_"' file | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also just sort on the character:

```sh
tr -cd a\\n <file | paste - ./file | LC_ALL=C sort -rk1,1 | cut -f2-
```

Here's what your example looks like after being `tr`anslated and `paste`d before it is piped into `sort`:

```
aa  baseball
aaa aardvark
aaaaaaaaaa  a man a plan a canal panama
a   cat
a   bat
    bill
```

Then `sort` gets it and, all things being equal, sorts the shorter keys before the longer keys but in `-r`everse, and its output is...

```
aaaaaaaaaa  a man a plan a canal panama
aaa aardvark
aa  baseball
a   cat
a   bat
    bill
```

...and `cut` just strips away up to the first tab.

```
a man a plan a canal panama
aardvark
baseball
cat
bat
bill
```

Comment: @terdon - hey what happened to the comments? They were good! But now I'm confused - LC...=C is better for speed and edge cases, but how can your `sort` put b before a in any language? I think maybe it's about the tab.

Comment: I deleted them since I added it to your answer. It's not sorting b before a but space (which is the first field for lines without a) before a.

Comment: @terdon - there's no space. It's a tab.

Comment: OK, it's still sorted before the a.

Comment: @terdon - I believe it, but it confuses me. I'm curious about it is all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input.txt |
while IFS= read -r a; do
    b=${a//[^a]}
    echo "${#b} $a"
done | sort -rn | sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Schwartzian transform has been mentioned, I'm surprised to see that no-one has yet posted a pure Perl implementation of one:

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_ }{ print map { $_->[0] } sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } map { [$_, $_ =~ tr/a//] } @a' file
a man a plan a canal panama
aardvark
baseball
cat
bat
bill
```

Each line of the file is pushed to `@a`, then once the file has been read, the count of the character `a` is used to sort the array.

Since counting the number of occurrences of a character isn't that expensive a function to compute, a more concise method would be just to use sort by itself:

```
$ perl -ne 'push @a, $_ }{ print sort { $b =~ tr/a// <=> $a =~ tr/a// } @a' file
a man a plan a canal panama
aardvark
baseball
cat
bat
bill
```