# List directory hierarchy with files before subdirectories

Tags: bash, sort, tree

I've been trying to sort output with either `tree` or `find`, and end up getting about the same results each time of drilling down to deeper directories before files higher up in the tree. What I'm trying to do is store the directories of interest in a lua table with the directory as the key for sub tables of files.

I'm using `tree -fi -noreport {Foo,Baz}`

```
Foo
Foo/Foo.Build.cs
Foo/Private
Foo/Private/Foos
Foo/Private/Foos/Bars
Foo/Private/Foos/Bars/BaseBar.cpp
Foo/Private/Foo.cpp
Foo/Private/FOOPCH.h
Baz
Baz/Baz.Build.cs
```

I want the results to look like:

```
Foo
Foo/Foo.Build.cs
Foo/Private
Foo/Private/Foo.cpp
Foo/Private/FOOPCH.h
Foo/Private/Foos
Foo/Private/Foos/Bars
Foo/Private/Foos/Bars/BaseBar.cpp
Baz
Baz/Baz.Build.cs
```

`tree fi -noreport {Foo,Baz} | sort -t '/'` isn't working. I tried using the solution from [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219665/how-to-sort-file-by-character-occurrences-per-line), which is `tree | awk '{print gsub("/","/"), $0}' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-`. If I do that I lose the relationship between directories and files.

How can I sort so files at the same depth show up before directories?

Comment: have you run `find` with the -depth option?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that it doesn't exactly give me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display the directory names first, then jump in and display only filenames:

```
find . ! -name . -type d -print -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -maxdepth 1 ! -type d' {} {} \;
```