# How can I count number of a specific character in a column for each line and add as new column using AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to count the number of `N` characters in the second column of a file and then print this count to the third column.
Example input file (tab-separated):

```
sample1 TCTNG
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN
sample3 GGGNNNTC
```

Desired output (tab-separated):

```
sample1 TCTNG   1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN  2
sample3 GGGNNNTC    3
```

I can get a messy version doing the following, but I would like a one-liner, preferably in `awk`.

```
> awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' file.txt | awk -FN '{print NF-1}' > NCount.txt
> paste -d '\t' file.txt NCount.txt

sample1 TCTNG   
    1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN  
    2
sample3 GGGNNNTC
    3
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if a line's column 2 contains no `N`s ?

Comment: Some of the output lines (***but not all***) listed as output from the messy version contain ***trailing TABs*** (the listed input file also contains TABs *between* the columns). Is that intentional? Is it a consequence of trailing TABs in the input file? Can you clarify? Preferably by [editing (changing) your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/670184/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gsub()` function returns the number of made substitutions.  You may use this fact to count the number of `N` characters in the 2nd field and to add this number as a new field on each line:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{ $3 = gsub("N","N",$2) }; 1' file
sample1 TCTNG 1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN 2
sample3 GGGNNNTC 3
```

The output is caused by the trailing `1` (it is equivalent to using `{ print }` or `{ print $0 }`).

Set the value of the special variable `OFS` to use another field delimiter than the default (space) in the output.  Here I'm using whatever the input field delimiter is set to:

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $3 = gsub("N","N",$2) }; 1' file
sample1 TCTNG   1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN      2
sample3 GGGNNNTC        3
```

---

Simirlarly in Perl, but using the `tr` operator in place of `gsub()`:

```
$ perl -MEnglish -a -F '\t' -e 'BEGIN { $OFS="\t"; $ORS="\n" } print @F, ($F[1] =~ tr/N/N/)' file
sample1 TCTNG   1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN      2
sample3 GGGNNNTC        3
```

Comment: I am having issues with a newline between the 2nd and 3rd columns, making the count in the 3rd column appear on the next line (as in the "messy" version I shared in the original post). Could this have something to do with an invisible newline character after the 2nd column?

Comment: @eam12 I can't really reproduce what you're seeing. I can get quite funky results by converting the input to a DOS-formatted text file, but not really so that the count appears on a new line by itself.  Make sure that your data is a Unix text file.

Comment: Hmmm. It's a BLAST output file that was created in Unix. I'll look into it more. Must be something strange on my end. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, gsub(/N/,"",$2)}' file
sample1 TCTNG   1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN  2
sample3 GGGNNNTC    3
```

Based on :
[How to print the count of pattern at each line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464818/how-to-print-the-count-of-pattern-at-each-line)

Answer (score 2):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'put ~$/.join("").chars if m:g/N*/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
sample0 TCTG
sample1 TCTNG
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN
sample3 GGGNNNTC
```

Sample Output:

```
sample0 TCTG    0
sample1 TCTNG   1
sample2 CCNGGGGGTN  2
sample3 GGGNNNTC    3
```

Above code: print the Raku `$_` topic variable first (followed by a `\t`), then print a count of the the `join("")` -concatenated `N` matches, and add as a new column to the end of each line.

https://raku.org