# Bash script to find maximum number of a certain character (".") in any single line of a file

Tags: bash, text-processing

There is a file with an unknown number of lines. In the file each line contains unknown many periods (`.`).

How can I find the maximum period number? I am *not* interested in finding the line that contains the most periods.

For example: Processing the file content below in bash should give the answer "4".

```
one.one
two.two.two
three.three.three.three
four..four.
five..five..
six...six
```

Comment: Quite related: [How to count the number of a specific character in each line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18736). Take an answer there, sort the results and get the last line, you have the answer.

Comment: `tr -dc '\n.' | sort | tail -n1 | wc -m` https://stackoverflow.com/q/8629410

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^.]/,""); len=length(); if (len>max) {max=len}} END{printf("Largest count of \".\": %d\n",max)}' file.txt
```

This will, for every line, replace all characters that are *not* `.`, by "nothing" (i.e. remove everything that is not a `.`). Then, it will count the length of the remaining string, and store the largest value found in `max`. At end-of-file, it will print the result.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can count the number of a specific character, and leave the text unchanged for further processing, such as printing the line itself, or counting another character. gsub returns the number of replacements.

```
awk '{ nDot = gsub ("[.]", "."); etc .. }'
```

Answer (score 3):

The awk-less answer:

```
sed 's/[^.]//g' test.dat | wc -L
```

In other words, keep only the dots, and use the -L option of `wc`: `-L, --max-line-length: print the maximum display width`

Comment: Note that `wc -L` is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2):

Let's generate an example,

```
cat >file <<'X'
this.world.
this
1.2.3.4.5
all.is.done
X
```

With `perl`

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { $x = $n if ($n = ($_ =~ y/.//)) > $x } print "$x\n"' file
4
```

With `awk`

```
awk '{ gsub("[^.]", ""); if ((n = length($0)) > x) { x = n } } END { print x }' file
4
```

With `tr` and a non-POSIX extended version of `wc`

```
tr -cd '.\n' <file | wc -L
4
```

Comment: The stderr output format of `dd` is only specified in the POSIX locale, and even there, all it says is it shall be `"%u+%u records out\n", <number of whole output blocks>, <number of partial output blocks>` (note that leading blanks are also allowed). GNU `dd` doesn't appear to be compliant in that regard.

Comment: And DD reports bytes and not characters, so if you to generalize to any character it won't work. Only the `awk` and the `wc -L` version will work on characters coded in more than one byte.

Comment: Ok. Option removed. Thank you both

Comment: The version with `tr` and `wc -L` works OK for me (at least with French characters, assuming UTF-8 encoded input file).

Comment: In UTF-8, bytes with a `0` upper bit can only be 1-byte characters, bytes of multi-bytes characters always have a `1` upper bit, so the ASCII for `.` cannot match a byte of a multi-byte character.

Comment: @xenoid, GNU `wc -L` reports the display width, not the number of characters. See [Get the display width of a string of characters](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/258551)

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk` could be as follows.
We need to realize that the following equality holds:

- `number of fields = number of delimiters + 1`

Note that adding a `0` to the operand in arithmetic comparison, even though not always necessary, is a good practice to inculcate. At least it helps me think about one less thing, for it becomes an auto reflex coding action. Since `Awk` does not provide separate operators for arithmetic nd string comparisons, hence coercion is needed to help disambiguate a string from a math operand or rather context.

```
$ awk -F '[.]' '
    NF>m+0 {m=NF}
    END {print --m}
' file
4
```

```
$ awk '
    gsub(/[^.]+/, "") &&
    ! index(t, $0) { t = $0 }
    END { print length(t) }
' file
```

```
$ perl -lne '
    my $k = tr/.//;
    $k > $m and $m = $k;
    }{ print $m+0;
' file
```

The `GNU sed` editor can also be used in conjunction with the binary calculator `bc` utility. Idea is we keep lines stripped off of all non-dots and the current longest string of pure dots is held in hold. At `eof`, we transform the dots into an actionable `bc` code to generate the number of those dots.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    s/[^.]+//g;G
    /^(.*)..*\n\1$/!ba
    s/\n.*//;h;:a
    $!d;g;s/./1+/g;s/$/0/
'  file | bc -l
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation? And is m+0 really needed there?

Answer (score 0):

JAAOV  (Just another awk obfuscating  variant...)

```
awk 'gsub(/[^.]/,"") { print | "wc -L" }'
```